# promise polyfill not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, polyfills

I have literally tried all the polyfills available on the internet related to promises. In some cases, I succeeded in avoiding the console error in IE. But the issue is, even if it does not throw any error, there is still no output. I am using the third party library - dom-to-image.js to convert my html table to png image. any help or pointers highly appreciated.

P.S. - I am not using node in my project.

Comment: Please add some code where you include JavaScript library files and

Comment: hi..I have aaded the polyfill script to my index page using script tag

Comment: Yes, but why you're afraid of posting some code. Which library and version you're using ? What is the error in Dev console ?

Comment: dom-to-image.js does not support IE,
Internet Explorer is not (and will not be) supported, as it does not support SVG <foreignObject> tag

Comment: hi Ahmad, thats why we use polyfills

Comment: IE will not be supported unfortunately due to the fact that it does not support <foreignObject> SVG tag and without <foreignObject> this library will not work